# Retrieve and click the checkbox from Ext model programmatically

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to retrieve and click the checkbox "Alabama" programmatically? i have tried many ways but fail to retrieve the checkbox on the ext combobox model.

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function() {
    Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'combobox',
        renderTo: document.body,
        fieldLabel: 'Combobox',
        labelAlign: 'right',
        displayField: 'name',
        id: 'multiComboBox',
        multiSelect: true,
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-boundlist-item">', '<input type="checkbox" />', '{name}', '</div>', '</tpl>'),
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: [{
                type: 'string',
                name: 'name'
            }],
            data: [{
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "name": "Arkansas"
            }, {
                "name": "California"
            }]
        }),
        queryMode: 'local',
        listeners: {
            select: function (combo, records) {
                var node;
                
                Ext.each(records, function (rec) {
                    node = combo.getPicker().getNode(rec);
                    /*Ext.get(node).down('input').set({
                        checked: true
                    });*/
                    Ext.get(node).down('input').dom.checked = true;
                });
            },
            beforedeselect: function (combo, rec) {
                var node = combo.getPicker().getNode(rec);

                /*Ext.get(node).down('input').set({
                    checked: undefined
                });*/
                Ext.get(node).down('input').dom.checked = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have done something like below. it was selected and show the name on the field. However, when i opened the dropdown list, the checkbox isn't checked. the following code cannot direct to  select function of the listener

```
Ext.getCmp('multiComboBox').select('Alabama')
```

Comment: Are you trying to set an option selected by default?
If so, maybe setting the [value](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-value) config  instead of manually doing it via `Ext.getCmp` might help.